# Catch JSON deserialization error in WCF service

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest

I have a basic WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "object/{id}")]
void MyMethod(String id, MyType myObject);
```

When I call this service with valid JSON data, it works as expected. And when I call it with invalid JSON data, I get request error, which is also expected.

However, this error contains a stack trace and a generic message.

My question is how can I catch this error and return my own message or html page?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<customErrors />` on the `<system.web>` section of web.config and/or you can use the Application_Error event on Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       // Your error handling stuff
       System.Web.HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
       System.Exception ex = context.Server.GetLastError();

       context.Server.ClearError();

       Response.Redirect("CustomError.aspx");
}
```

Comment: I don't have a Global.asax in my project. I tried adding it, but it is never called.
I have also tried the `<customErrors />` solution, but it never redirects to the new page.

Comment: How are you hosting your service? IIS? Self-hosted?

Comment: Both solutions should work. Paste the code of your Global.asax declaration, is must start like this: public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication { ... }